# R shiny UI 'filter' issue

Tags: r, shiny

I have been able to have similar pieces of code working perfectly with the UI running from within server.
When running UI outside server everything works fine.
When running UI in server without *observeEvent* the UI loads correctly.

However I get this error when using *observeEvent*

```
Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 3919 or 1, not size 0.
ℹ Input `..1` is `c(...)`.
  90: <Anonymous>
```

The sample that gives error is as follows

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

pNames<-data.frame("Birth_Date" = as.Date(c("1989-12-05", '1943-03-18', '1989-12-05', '1943-03-18', '1989-12-05', '1943-03-18', '1989-12-05', '1943-03-18', '1989-12-05', '1943-03-18',' 1989-12-05'), format = "%Y-%m-%d"  ), 
                   "service" = c('Fix', 'Price', 'Unable to fix', 'Fix', 'Price', 'Unable to fix', 'Fix', 'Price', 'Unable to fix', 'Fix', 'Price'), 
                   "problem" = c("Warning Lights", "A Sputtering Engine", "Poor Fuel Economy", "Dead Battery", "Flat Tires", "Brakes Squeaking or Grinding", "Alternator Failure", 
                                 "Broken Starter Motor", "Dead Battery", "Broken Starter Motor", "Warning Lights" ))

ui <- uiOutput("uiHome")

server <- function(input, output, session)
  ({
    output$uiHome <- renderUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        dateRangeInput(
          inputId = "dobInput",
          label = "Date of Birth",
          start = min(pNames$Birth_Date),
          end   = max(pNames$Birth_Date),
          min = min(pNames$Birth_Date),
          max = max(pNames$Birth_Date)
        ),
        
        selectizeInput(
          "serviceInput",
          label = "Service",
          choices =  unique(pNames[['service']]),
          multiple = TRUE,
          options = list(maxItems = 1 , placeholder = "Enter a Service..")
        ),
        
        selectizeInput(
          "problemInput",
          label = "Problem",
          choices =  unique(pNames[['problem']]),
          multiple = TRUE,
          options = list(maxItems = 1 , placeholder = "Enter a Problem...")
        )
      ),
      mainPanel()
    )))
    
    observeEvent(input$dobInput,
                 {
 
                  
                   print(head(pNames)) 
                   baseFilter <-
                     if (is.null(input$problemInput)) {
                       unique(filter(
                         pNames,
                         c(
                           pNames$Birth_Date >= input$dobInput[1] &
                             pNames$Birth_Date <= input$dobInput[2]
                         )
                       ))
                     }
                   print(baseFilter)
                 },
                 ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can please also include `pNames` (e.g. by using `dput`) to make a reproducible example.

Comment: do you expect baseFilter to be reactive? This is not the case. If pNames depends on baseFilter it also won't update either.

Comment: @starja Included pNames in edit

Comment: @Waldi yes baseFilter is expected to update when dobInput is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that works. The problem was that you tried to filter something when `input$dobInput` was not defined yet (then it is `NULL`), so I added an `req` to the observer. However, I'm not sure what you exactly want to do with the `baseFilter` and what should be `unique`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

pNames<-data.frame("Birth_Date" = as.Date(c("1989-12-05", '1943-03-18', '1989-12-05', '1943-03-18', '1989-12-05', '1943-03-18', '1989-12-05', '1943-03-18', '1989-12-05', '1943-03-18',' 1989-12-05'), format = "%Y-%m-%d"  ), 
                   "service" = c('Fix', 'Price', 'Unable to fix', 'Fix', 'Price', 'Unable to fix', 'Fix', 'Price', 'Unable to fix', 'Fix', 'Price'), 
                   "problem" = c("Warning Lights", "A Sputtering Engine", "Poor Fuel Economy", "Dead Battery", "Flat Tires", "Brakes Squeaking or Grinding", "Alternator Failure", 
                                 "Broken Starter Motor", "Dead Battery", "Broken Starter Motor", "Warning Lights" ))

ui <- uiOutput("uiHome")

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  output$uiHome <- renderUI({fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput(
        inputId = "dobInput",
        label = "Date of Birth",
        start = min(pNames$Birth_Date),
        end   = max(pNames$Birth_Date),
        min = min(pNames$Birth_Date),
        max = max(pNames$Birth_Date)
      ),
      
      selectizeInput(
        "serviceInput",
        label = "Service",
        choices =  unique(pNames[['service']]),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(maxItems = 1 , placeholder = "Enter a Service..")
      ),
      
      selectizeInput(
        "problemInput",
        label = "Problem",
        choices =  unique(pNames[['problem']]),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(maxItems = 1 , placeholder = "Enter a Problem...")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel()
  ))})
  
  observeEvent(input$dobInput, {
    req(input$dobInput)
    print(head(pNames))
    
    if (is.null(input$problemInput)) {
      baseFilter <- pNames %>% 
        filter(Birth_Date >= input$dobInput[1] &
                 Birth_Date <= input$dobInput[2]) %>% 
        distinct(problem, .keep_all = TRUE)
      
      print(baseFilter)
    }
  },
  ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: req(input$dobInput) works :), though I actually need other inputs as well it runs perfectly with that one req(). Thanks much!

I use unique since its from a large database with thousands of repeating fields, I didn't test the code without it till now and it seems to work the same, so no use for it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`eventReactive`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html) instead of `observe` to update `baseFilter`:

```
baseFilter <- eventReactiveEvent(input$dobInput,
                 {               
                     if (is.null(input$problemInput)) {
                       unique(filter(
                         pNames,
                         c(
                           pNames$Birth_Date >= input$dobInput[1] &
                             pNames$Birth_Date <= input$dobInput[2]
                         )
                       ))
                     }
                 },
                 ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

If you don't do so, `baseFilter()` won't be a reactive function updated according to input.

Comment: I definitely want it to be reactive